# how can i send compressed data (JSON) from client to server

Tags: json

utlitmately the data size from client to server has to be reduced and the speed has to be increased

Comment: How many KB of data is being sent over the wire?  Have you used any profiling tools to see where your bottlenecks are?

Answer (score 0):

Run it through a compressor, like zip? That said, if size of json is an issue, you probably should take a long hard look at what your're doing.